# Ios Development Swift class & Subclasses

Tags: swift, class, inheritance, init

I have created a class with variable stored properties of type Condition. I initialized the class and everything seems to be fine.

```
enum Condition {
    case poor
    case fair
    case excellent
}

class Shoe {

    var color: Condition?
    var laces: Condition?

    init(color: Condition, laces:Condition) {
        self.color = color
        self.laces = laces
    }
}
```

when I subclass my base class I am having compiler errors.

```
class Nike: Shoe {
    var texture: Condition?
    var sole: Condition?

    override init(color: Condition, laces: Condition) {
        self.texture = texture
        self.sole = sole
        super.init(color: Condition, laces: Condition)
    }
}
```

Because of the variables in (override init), I am receiving a compiler error that says I am assigning a property to itself, which I thought I had to do to initialize the values?

**Step 1:** Provide values for the properties of the subclass.

**Step 2:** once the sublass is initialized, provide values for properties of the base class.

Comment: Not related but why are the properties optional since the initializer is non-optional and the enum can be only one of the three cases??

Comment: you are assigning the properties to themselves. self.texture and texture are the same property in this case.

Comment: Vadian, I am new to swift and coding in general. I thought the objects had to be optional because the enums had 3 different choices and one of the answers may not be the correct answer. With that said it would have been an error on my part not making the initializer optional. But after you asked this question i'm thinking the objects dont have to be optional.

Comment: Simple rule: if you wrote a required initializer passing non-optional parameters use non-optional properties.

Comment: Vadian understood, thank you so much.

Comment: Stupid thought, considering those who have commented and answered. But  if you are subclassing `Shoe` along with overriding it's `init(color: laces:)`, why aren't you calling `super(init)` at all?

Comment: dfd super init is being called in  override int

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to add `texture` and `sole` arguments to `Nike.init`. Also, you need to pass the arguments through to `super.init` where you currently wrote `Condition`. Try this:

```
class Nike: Shoe {
    var texture: Condition?
    var sole: Condition?

    override init(color: Condition, laces: Condition, texture: Condition, sole: Condition) {
        self.texture = texture
        self.sole = sole
        super init(color: color, laces: laces)
    }
}
```

Comment: If i do not want my subclass to inherit the condition chosen in the super class is this a problem. I want the subclass to have the same variables but I want a user of an app to be able to choose the conditions. So i was using class inheritance because of  DRY

Comment: You are initializing all the properties. They are initialized with the values you passed into super. They are also var properties, so you can modify them after they are initialized.